# How to include network drivers in the initramfs for PXE booting?

Tags: centos7, ethernet, pxe-boot, drivers, kernel-modules

I am working on setting up PXE Booting on a HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen10 Server. The server has a HPE Ethernet 100Gb 1-port 842QSFP28 Adapter for the network interface.

We have a custom linux kernel that has been specifically fine tuned for some heavy numericalcomputation tasks. When this custom kernel is loaded from the local storage, the network card does not get loaded. This is probably because the network adapter requires 3rd party drivers. I have obtained the drivers from HPE website.

At the moment, to keep the machine operational a standard kernel (3.10 with CentOS 7) is running. After studying the driver documentation and the installation instruction, I've found that there are some options for the install script that makes it possible to install the required kernel modules for a target kernel. When this option is used, the kernel modules get installed into the directory `/lib/modules/4.4.47/extra/`. Using this, I generate an initramfs file using `dracut -f /path/to/custom-initramfs.img /path/to/custom-vmlinuz --kver 4.4.47`

I've deployed the custom initramfs and the kernel image to the tftpboot directory and configured the pxelinux.cfg accordingly. When I reboot the server, it successfully detects the the kernel and the initramfs but then after some time it gets stuck at trying to discovering network. I simply get the message "Trying to detect network". It then changes to "Retrying in 110 seconds". Finally it times out and remains stuck.

So for some reason, the network drivers do not get loaded. When I use `zcat` to verify the contents of the initramfs, I can see that the driver modules are included in it. I am not sure how to proceed further. The driver documentation does not contain much information about how to install for PXE booting. Can anyone advise what else I can try next? Thank you.